# How we detect when the app comes in Foreground by clicking on MPNowPlayingInfoCenter view in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, mpnowplayinginfocenter

We are using AVPlayer in our app and when app is in background state and user taps on the **MPNowPlayingInfoCenter** view and app launch than how we detect that app is launched by on click of **MPNowPlayingInfoCenter** view.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try `UIApplicationDelegate.applicationWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: It called in all cases i.e, when come in foreground by clicking app icon and by clicking MPNowPlayingInfoCenter View. But i want specifically only when come in foreground click by MPNowPlayingInfoCenter View

Comment: In the AppDelegate implement the handleOpenUrl method, i think this will be called when app is opened from some other app.

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi thanks for your response but it is not called.